# Magento2. How to create custom form for email sending in admin GRID form?

Tags: magento2, email, grid, custom

I have items in admin-GRID. When I click on any item I open the form with some information, some of whom are email. I need to implement a custom form with a button "Send" to send email.
What can I do that?

Comment: How do you achieve this?